# printf not working in AVR Studio 7

Tags: printf, avr

Ok, so suddenly printf is not working in AVR studio, i dont know what happened, this is the code, but it doesn't output anything to the debug window:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
    printf("a");
    }
}
```

Comment: What "debug window"? Don't you have to redirect the printf stream before using it? Was this code doing anything on Atmel Studio 6?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830019/atmel-sensor-using-printf/15834476#15834476

Comment: Imeant the output window, this is only code to test if the printf is working, but it doesent output anything. I noticed that i neet to put  `#include <stdio.h>`, but it is the same, nothing on output.

Comment: Since you said suddenly, are you sure this is working previously with Studio 7 or studio 6 ?

Comment: Yes, and it should work, i cant thin of a reason why it wont work.

Answer (score -2):

It works for serial port. Never used it with debugger. Try using variables instead, and reading their content.